# How can one justify that mixed second order partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ where $f$ is a holomorfic function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ are equal?

Tags: complex-analysis

How can one justify that mixed second order partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ where $f$ is a holomorfic function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ are equal? I'm wondering about it but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is holomorphic on some domain $D$, we know the Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied on $D$.  That is,
$$
u_x = v_y\qquad\text{and}\qquad u_y = -v_x
$$
**Theorem 1:**
If $f(z)$ is analytic on $D$, then so is $f'(z)$.

The consequence of this theorem is that second partial derivatives exists and are continuous on $D$.

**Theorem 2:**
If the mixed partial derivatives exist and are continuous at $z_0$, then 
$$
u_{xy} = v_{xy}
$$
It follows from the fact that since $f$ is holomorphic and Theorem 1, Theorem 2 holds.